# Find out what process is listening on a specific port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, netstat, ss

For the first time in my life, I am unable to figure out what process is listening on a specific port in Linux :)

This is an Ubuntu Server 22.04 installation, running K8s. There is an ingress controller in the cluster that is binding to ports 80 and 443, and I know this works because:

```
:~# curl localhost
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

:~# curl localhost:443
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

~# curl https://localhost:443 -k
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out what process binds to those ports, and how. I did try using `ss`, but nothing shows up:

```
:~# ss -tlnpu | grep 80
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096          192.168.13.191:2380       0.0.0.0:*    users:(("etcd",pid=1452,fd=8))           
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096               127.0.0.1:2380       0.0.0.0:*    users:(("etcd",pid=1452,fd=7))           

:~# ss -tlnpu | grep 443
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096                       *:6443             *:*    users:(("kube-apiserver",pid=1546,fd=7))
```

How can I figure out the actual process that is listening on the ports?

Comment: Sanity check: what address does `localhost` resolve to?

Comment: Look at `iptables` rules, particularly the `nat` tables where you will have `DNAT` rules. Maybe your ports 80 & 443 are being forwarded elsewhere or rewritten to different ports

Comment: Are you running the `ss` command within the appropriate container? The processes managed by Kubernetes (K8s) could be in a separate network namespace, so a host-level `ss` might not see them without the `-N <namespace>` or `--net=<namespace>` option.

Comment: @StephenKitt - I did check `iptables`, but I didn't think to look at the `nat` tables as well :)  . @roaima is right - there are `DNAT` rules rewriting the packets. If you would post that as an answer, I would gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, it looks like I see you're running Kubernetes, so there's a good chance you could find the containers listening to that port using a docker command:

```
$ docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}"
CONTAINER ID        NAMES                    PORTS
a690f047d3c8        quizzical_sanderson      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 8443/tcp         
431ff622ad62        tender_payne             0.0.0.0:9191->9090/tcp
78941a2ee170        awx_task                 8052/tcp
2f5fc70ac576        awx_web                  0.0.0.0:80->8052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->8053/tcp
```

You could see the container `awx_web` forwards ports 80 and 443 from the host to ports 8052 and 8053 respectively in the container's private network namespace.

You could also just run `docker ps`, without the `--format` argument. I used the `--format` argument to make it more readable and convenient.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not apply. Even if it was a container, I should have been able to see the process using `ss` (in the case of docker, the process is usually `docker-proxy`). Also, this is a recent k8s version, so it uses `containerd` instead of `docker` as the runtime.